# Any library or proposed solution for subgraph (path) matching within a graph?

Tags: java, graph, pattern-matching, subgraph

For example, there is a graph, which can be represented as an adjacency matrix as

`G = {{ 0, 1, 0 }, { 1, 0, 1 }, { 1, 0, 0 }}`

Thus, there are four **directed** **edges**:

```
node_1 to node_2, node_2 to node_3, node_2 to node_1 and node_3 to node_1.
```

What I want is to calculate the **similarity between subgraph (path)** {node_2 to node_3} and **subgraph (path)** {node_2 to node_3 to node_1}.

What I can found the most is the subgraph isomorphism problem, which trying to determine if a subgraph matches (is a part of) a larger graph. This is not my desire.

My major task is to determine how similar two subgraphs (path) are, which both exist within a graph that I known.

Any existing approaches you could recommend? Papers? Example code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you measure "how similar two subgraphs are."  Isomorphism is one way (which you already said you didn't want).  What metric are you using or do you want to use?

Comment: @TravisJ Thx for the comment. This is what I want to figure out. "How to measure the similarity between two subgraphs (paths) within a graph". I'm trying to proposed a solution to this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) measures the difference between two sequences by counting the number of single-element editions needed to change one sequence into the other.

If you store the vertex sequence of each path in a list or array you can calculate the distance using the following implementation (assuming you have a `Vertex` type):

```
int levenshteinDistance(List<Vertex> path, int lenPath, List<Vertex> other, int lenOther) {
    if (path.equals(other)) return 0;
    if (lenPath == 0) return lenOther;
    if (lenOther == 0) return lenPath;

    int cost;
    if (path.get(lenPath - 1).equals(other.get(lenOther - 1))) {
        cost = 0;
    } else {
        cost = 1;
    }

    int dist1 = levenshteinDistance(path, lenPath - 1, other, lenOther) + 1;
    int dist2 = levenshteinDistance(path, lenPath, other, lenOther - 1) + 1;
    int dist3 = levenshteinDistance(path, lenPath - 1, other, lenOther - 1) + cost;
    return Math.min(dist1, Math.min(dist2, dist3));
}
```

This is inefficient, though, as it recomputes the distance for many subsequences. A more efficient implementation can be found at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Java. Note that it uses `String` as input, but it should be straightforward to reimplement it to use arrays.

Comment: Thx. By using this, do you mean to measure how many nodes that one path need to transform into another path? Or, could you give more specific examples? I just google the Levenshtein distance, but never use it before. Thx a million.